# How come pandas 'select' results in the examples don't match?

Tags: pandas

Looking at the examples in http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#query-via-data-columns for how to use 'select' in hdf5, how come `'In [310]'` results differ than those of `'In [311]'`, aren't those queries supposed to be identical?

And on the same note, I would except `'In [310]'` results to be a subset of `'In [309]'` results, but they are not... Is there something I am missing in how select works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

310 and 311 should be the same, and 310 should be a subset of 309.

This was a very subtle bug in how freq reconversion on a queried DataFrame was reconstructed, resolved [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5674). Docs are built daily at 5pm. Should be correct then.